# Google Apps Script - Creating multiple copies of one ss, rename and transfer protections

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script

I am trying to create 29 copies of a single Google Sheet spreadsheet all within the same workbook, rename each spreadsheet, and transfer the sheet protections (and unprotected ranges). My code so far will transfer the protections correctly, but it only creates one copy of the spreadsheet and names the spreadsheet as my entire array [ "#3","#4","#5", etc.].

I am attempting to duplicate the sheet and protections off of a spreadsheet titled, "#2". I want the additional 30 sheets to each be named, "#3","#4","#5", etc. (up to #31). I have included the code below. It will throw an error stating the sheet name can't be > 100 characters, but if you make the array < 100 it will do what I described above. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Grab template to make duplicates
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("#2");
  const p = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];

  // Output new sheet and transfer protections
  const sheetNamesArray = ["#3","#4","#5","#6","#7","#8","#9","#10","#11","#12","#13","#14","#15","#16","#17","#18","#19","#20","#21","#22","#23","#24","#25","#26","#27","#28","#29","#30","#31"];
  const duplicateSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheetNamesArray);
  const p2 = duplicateSheet.protect();
  
  for (var counter = 0; counter <= 29; counter++) {
    setName(sheetNamesArray[counter]);
};

  // Create multiple sheets from the original sheet
  function nameNewSheets() {
    var sheetNames = ["#3","#4","#5","#6","#7","#8","#9","#10","#11","#12","#13","#14","#15","#16","#17","#18","#19","#20","#21","#22","#23","#24","#25","#26","#27","#28","#29","#30","#31"];
    sheetNames.forEach(function nameNewSheets() {
      duplicateSheetWithProtections(sheetNames);
    });
  }

  if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
    // Copy editors
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    }

    // Get all unprotected ranges from original sheet
    const ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
    const newRanges = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      newRanges.push(duplicateSheet.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
  }

  // Unprotect the ranges in the new output
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);
}
```

Comment: That's because you need a `for` loop!

Comment: Right, I understand that. I just started learning code about two weeks ago, so I am a little unclear as to where it needs to be incorporated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to edit your for loop, adding a variable.
Also clean your code, the brackets do not seem right.

```js
  // Create multiple sheets from the original sheet
  function nameNewSheets() {
    var sheetNames = ["#3","#4","#5","#6","#7","#8","#9","#10","#11","#12","#13","#14","#15","#16","#17","#18","#19","#20","#21","#22","#23","#24","#25","#26","#27","#28","#29","#30","#31"];
    sheetNames.forEach(function nameNewSheets(sheetName) {
      duplicateSheetWithProtections(sheetName);
    });
  }

function duplicateSheetWithProtections(sheetName) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // Grab template to make duplicates
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("#2");
  const p = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];

  // Output new sheet and transfer protections
  const duplicateSheet = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheetName);
  const p2 = duplicateSheet.protect();
  
  if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
    // Copy editors
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    }

    // Get all unprotected ranges from original sheet
    const ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
    const newRanges = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
      newRanges.push(duplicateSheet.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
  }

  // Unprotect the ranges in the new output
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);

}
```

Comment: I just tried using your guidance again and it worked! Thank you so much for the help!!

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't hesitate to mark the answer as correct